# How to make the character interact with the scene's background?

Tags: leonardo.ai

I want to decorate a children's book so i'm trying to get my character to do all kinds of things with a background generated with the AI tool. but I cannot get the tool to do what I want

I have the following character:
https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/6d3d2e40-0b1e-4de9-9389-68092e3e285c/3D_Animation_Style_A_little_girl_named_Shira_multiple_poses_an_0.jpg

And I have a background/scene with i upload and use as "image to image":
https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/6dc8876d-6830-45cf-83b7-9d95cb898f91/3D_Animation_Style_a_little_girls_room_scene_nighttime_the_roo_0.jpg

How can I make the character blend with the scene ?
For example, I want the character to sit on a chair, or sit on a bed, or play in the middle of the room ?

#### Sitting on a chair

Prompt:

> cartoon, personality: Introduce Shira with a close-up shot. Focus on
> her curious and wide-eyed expression, capturing her sense of wonder
> and innocence, Shira has a red curly hair with brown eyes and white
> shirt. Shira is sitting on the chair which is located in the left side
> of the room

- Image to image strength: 0.37
- Result - bad, two characters for some reason and there's not even a chair, and why the mat got replaced with a table(?):
  https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/e08824e3-a710-4c6b-a798-853ad1a9778c/3D_Animation_Style_cartoon_personality_Introduce_Shira_with_a_0.jpg

#### Playing

Prompt:

> cartoon, personality: Introduce Shira with a close-up shot. Focus on
> her curious and wide-eyed expression, capturing her sense of wonder
> and innocence, Shira has a red curly hair with brown eyes and white
> shirt. Shira is playing with a train toy on the mat in the middle of
> the room

- Image to image: 0.37
- Result - Bad, no train toy and a scary woman on the side ... https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/51d1c1a4-ca5b-47a3-9eff-684ce57934a3/3D_Animation_Style_cartoon_personality_Introduce_Shira_with_a_0.jpg

What am i missing with all these AI tools ?
Does AI meant only for a single picture which isn't really consistent ?

In all the youtube videos they make it look really "simple" because they use a ChatGPT for a script ( that they don't care what the content of the words will be ) and then they generate the nice images
based on that with LeonardoAI - but they don't really care about the output images and details because they are just presenting what the tool can do.

I really wonder if those tools aren't just for "posters" like products ...

Comment: Did you not notice—or just not care—that the room itself is completely different every time you do an image to image transformation? In the [image from your other question](https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/355edaed-a02e-4b35-b6ca-1f72de23f8b3/variations/Default_cartoon_personality_Introduce_Shira_with_a_closeup_sho_0_355edaed-a02e-4b35-b6ca-1f72de23f8b3_1.jpg) in particular, the AI decided to add some body horror to the wall on the left, not to mention uncountable other changes. It'll be obvious to anyone who sees two within 5 minutes of each other

Comment: @Laurel you're right, i did noticed, but thought of handling it afterwards ... i'm a beginner in AI so i wanted to have the skills to perform the above first and then comeback to describe the room itself in more details